# Approval process using permission set

Tags: configuration

I have one approval process, where approver is selected from custom field which has filter to specific profile. now we have one requirement where submitter's manager can also approve the record. We don't want to remove filter from custom field. Is this possible using permission set or custom setting? If not then any other option

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "where approver is selected from custom field which has filter to specific profile" ?

Comment: I mean we have one custom field to select approver who can approve that particular record. Since this field is lookup to filter, we created lookup filer to specific profile

Comment: Sounds like you have a lookup to the user object w a filter for profile = X?  Now you want, for one specific user only to be able to select their manager, who can have any profile?  Can you just flag the manager as "OK" and then add logic to lookup filter as such?  Can do this w field on managers user record.  Custom perms or settings are tricky bc they evaluate for the running user so can't figure a way to do it that way.

Comment: Thanks gorav for your rply, as of now I am doing same thing but what happen if in future more user are asking for same thing. Basically I want to maintain a custom setting where for one user I will have  10 approver and he can select only from them

Comment: Ahh, interesting.  So for each user, you want to be able to specify N approvers, and then enable the user to be able to only.select one of them, correct?  For this you need to code up a page that allows a user to select the approver, and use custom object to model the authorized approvers for each submitter.  In the end you will still have a field on the record for "approver" but users will use an interface to select the approver.  You could build this out using visual workflow, but visualforce may be better

Comment: Yes you are right user will select only one of them, i don't want yo use vf page. Can you please give hint how it is possible to do using visual workflow

Comment: Yes will write up an answer using visual.flow but may take a few days.  Basic idea is that you lookup the possible approvers based on submitter and use a dynamic choice element to allow the submitter to select the approver and write the userId to the approver field on your object.

Comment: Will write up a coherent answer soon, but built a quick POC and captured the overview here: https://www.canva.com/design/DABotjIFGgo/Dvfi2dIkuE9D6L85nNyFRA/view